# How to parse Boolean Expressions in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, parsing, boolean, expression

I have a table that has a column "codes" as comma-separated values. Sample values below -

```
3fa, n38, iw9, 94a, l2v, 20z
92z, 29r, 02z, 99w, 00b, 92i
```

I want to find relevant rows, based on a boolean expression (with BODMAS rule)

**Example 1:**
If the input is **(3fa+n38)-02z**, the condition should translate to "find all records that have 3fa and n38, but not 02z". So this will return the first row.

**Example 2:**
If the input is **(((92z+00b)-20z)/02z)** the condition should translate to "find all records that have 92z and 00b, but not 20z OR records that have 02z.

So, the operators translation is as below

- `+` is treated as CONTAINS
- `-` is treated as NOT CONTAINS
- `/` is treated as OR

We have the flexibility of storing this codes column as either a comma separated value or as a string array. I am trying to build a Postgres function for it. I made it work via. dynamic SQL and REGEXP_REPLACE, but wanted to check if there was a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: That's not a simple question, that's a programming project. I am afraid that you will have to write that code yourself. Perhaps a question about part of that task would be appropriate.

Comment: You can construct the where clause with plpgsql or some other procedural language (possibly using recursive descent) , but since it is dynamic and contains column names, you'll still need dynamic SQL.